# C++: Hangman game

Tags: c++

I'm in the process of writing the program and stumbled upon a few issues.
The code reads a text file, which contains a list of 20 string words. The function `playHangman()` is supposed to read the file and randomly picks one word, which is displayed as asterisks in the console. The code works fine with local words when the function is called. For example Playhangman("stackOverflow"), will show the exact number of characters and will loop through them until the word is guessed right. If you take a look at the code, I'm calling the random word into the function. That word is stored as array. I know that that's not the proper way to do randomize, but for now, even if it picks the same word over and over, that's Ok, I just need to make sure it actually reads the array. The other thing is, when all characters are revealed, all the words on that text file are displayed, looks like I'm calling the entire content of the array instead of just that random word that's supposed to be generated.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string word[20];
string randomWord = word[rand() % 20];

int playHangman(string randomWord) {

    int misses = 0;
    int revealedletters = 0;
    string display = randomWord;

    ifstream textFile;

    // Open file
    textFile.open("hangman.txt");

    // Check if file exists
    if (!textFile) {
        cerr << "Unable to open text file\n";
        exit(1); // Call system to stop
    }
    else {
        cout << "File opened successfully. Program will continue...\n\n";


        // Loop through the content of the file
        while (textFile >> randomWord) {

            for (int i = 0; i < display.length(); i++)
                display[i] = '*';

            while(revealedletters < randomWord.length()) {
                cout << "Misses: " << misses << endl;
                cout << "Enter a letter in word ";
                cout << display << " : ";
                char response;
                cin >> response;

                bool goodGuess = false;
                bool duplicate = false;
                for (int i = 0; i < randomWord.length(); i++)
                    if (response == randomWord[i]) {
                        if (display[i] == randomWord[i]) {
                            cout << response << " is already in the word." << endl;
                            duplicate = true;
                            break;
                        }
                        else {
                            display[i] = randomWord[i];
                            revealedletters++;
                            goodGuess = true;
                        }
                    }

                if (duplicate)
                    continue;
                if (!goodGuess) {
                    misses++;
                    cout << response << " is not in word\n";
                }
            }
            cout << "You guessed right! The word is " << randomWord << ".\n";
        }
        return misses;
    }
}


    // TODO: Do you want to guess another word, Y/N?
int main () {

    playHangman(randomWord);

    // TODO: number of misses to guess the word.\n";
}
```

Comment: Why do you have these global variables at all?

Comment: You probably want to make reading the file of 20 words its own function.

Comment: `string display = randomWord;`Note that `randomWord` is an empty string at this point.  You randomly picked an empty string before the start of main. Since you never initialized the random number generator it will be the same empty sting each time you run your program (although not that this matters).

Comment: My advice is to move `word` and `randomWord` into main. seed your random number generator first. Then call a function that reads your file.  Then pick a random word. and call your play() function with all the file reading removed. All the play function needs is to be passed a single random word from the list.

Comment: *same empty sting* Filthy hobbitses and their magic swords. Won't give us our precious. No they won't.

Comment: I realize I have to move variables around, I have global just for testing. As for string `display = random`, wasn't that passed as globally declared?

Comment: @drescherjm What about looping through the content of the text file, should that be in play() function or within reading the file function?

Comment: @RochNoure General rule of thumb: A function should do as few things as possible, preferably one thing. A read file into list function should read a file into a list and return that list. Nothing more. Then you may want a function that picks a random word from that list and returns the word. The less stuff a function does the easier it is to get right and debug if you don't get it right.

Comment: I'm going to work on that, thank you. I still don't know why it's showing all words in that text file instead of just that one that was randomly picked. For example, after all letters were entered, once the last character matches, it spills all elements in the array. `Enter a letter in word telepho*e : n
You guessed right! The word is telephone.
You guessed right! The word is ghost.
You guessed right! The word is jellyfish.
You guessed right! The word is fancy.
You guessed right! The word is thirsty.
You guessed right! The word is noise.
You guessed right! The word is direful.
...`

Comment: ***I still don't know why it's showing all words in that text file instead of just that one that was randomly picked*** I recommend you try this code on a pc with an IDE with a debugger like Visual Studio. That way you will be able to single step through the code looking at the variables at each step to understand what your program is doing. If you don't have a debugger, placing cout statements in your code can help understand what is happening.

Comment: @drescherjm will do, thank you

Answer (score 0):

In your declaration and initialisation of your global variables:

```
string word[20];
string randomWord = word[rand() % 20];
```

`word` is an array of 20 empty strings and therefore `randomWord` will also always be empty.

In your `playHangman` function you have:

```
while (textFile >> randomWord) {

    for (int i = 0; i < display.length(); i++)
        display[i] = '*';

    while(revealedletters < randomWord.length()) {
       ......
```

This reads a single word from the file into `randomWord`, plays the game with that word then loops round to read the next word and plays again with that word. As `revealedletters` doesn't get reset the game will finish immediately if the first word is longer than the next one.

I think the code you actually want looks something like this (remove your global variables too):

```
std::string word;
std::vector<std::string> words;
while (textFile >> word) {
  words.push_back(word);
}
randomWord = words[rand() % words.size()];

std::string display = std::string(randomWord.size(), '*');

while(revealedletters < randomWord.length()) {
    ......
```

If you really must use arrays:

```
const size_t maxWords = 20;
std::string words[maxWords];
size_t wordCount = 0;
while (textFile >> word && wordCount < maxWords) {
  words[wordCount++] = word;
}
randomWord = words[rand() % wordCount];

std::string display = std::string(randomWord.size(), '*');

while(revealedletters < randomWord.length()) {
    ......
```

Comment: @RochNoure Yes, if you have some allergy to vectors you can use an array you just need to make sure your array is big enough to hold all the words in your file.

Comment: Britles It's because we have not studied vectors yet and I'm not supposed to implement them. I will take a look at the code you suggested, thank you!!

Comment: I get the error: `Decomposition declaration '[maxWords]' requires an initializer` and `Decomposition declaration cannot be declared with type 'std::string' (aka 'basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> >'); declared type must be 'auto' or reference to 'auto'` `Decomposition declarations are a C++17 extension`

Comment: the array size was in the wrong place (can you tell how often I use raw arrays in real c++ code?)

Comment: @Birtles I figured as much but you beat me to it. You're the best, thank you so much!!!